# Deleting duplicate records takes too much time

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I am trying to delete duplicate records from a mysql database. With the below command, it will delete all duplicates and will keep one row. In my database there are 300,000 records and I expect some 100,000 rows are duplicates.

The duplicates need to be deleted by the below command but the problem is, I had given the command in the evening after 9 hours it is still running.

```
 DELETE n1 FROM tableA n1,tableA n2 WHERE n1.title= n2.title AND n1.id > n2.id
```

What is happening? Can anyone explain?

Comment: Do you have an index defined on `title` for each table?

Comment: @Interrobang title are in one tableA only .the column title contains the title of article i want to delete the duplicate

Comment: this command seems okay and no reason for this time delay.You might have problems in table relation or records.

Comment: @KaidulIslamSazal i have earlier performed delete command for other column of same table.it took approx 886 seconds so i was expecting the similar time for this operation as well. should i repair the table and again run the command??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying:

```
select * from tableA as n1 join tableA as n2 on n1.title = n2.title AND n1.id > n2.id;
```

And to explain it: `n1.title = n2.title` does not use an index.

This query will be better:

```
delete from `t2` where `id` in (
    select cid from (
       select max(id) as cid from t2 group by title having count(*) > 1
    ) as c
);
```

Comment: i am trying your code.but can you please explain how your code is using index and my code is not using index

Comment: Using `group by ...` better than `title = title`,these two are the same are not using the index,unless you create a index by `title` field

Comment: i tried your code and seems same thing happening again it is executing but dont know how much time it will take

Comment: Not soon,but this is the best solution for your case

Comment: h0ow much time it will take approx can u please tell . i have approx 100000 duplicate data

Comment: you can run `show full processlist` to check status,I think it will consume 10-20 minutes in HDD

Comment: you rocks it done the job but it has deleted only 18000 records but i think it is more than 100000 .i am checking manually